# How to Select Table SQL To Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, dblink

I want to select data from SQL Server to Oracle (Toad Apps).

If from Oracle to SQL Server its done like this

```
Insert Into M_CLASSIFICATION_ORACLE 
SELECT * From OPENQUERY ([B1APPS], 'select * from V_Classification_Asset' ) AS derivedtbl_1
```

How about in Oracle (Toad apps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can able to do it by using `CREATE DATABASE LINK`:

**Create a Database Link to connect to SQL Server:**

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK link-name ...
```

**Query SQL Server using the Database Link:**

```
SELECT * FROM sqlserver-table-name@link-name;
```

**Documentation:** 
https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-administration/oracle-create-database-link/

**Calling Stored Procedure using Database Link:**
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/running-a-stored-procedure-across-db-link